# Access to UIKit from another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'd like to access to table view property in second view controller from first view controller with following code.

```
var story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) 
var view:VC2ViewController = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2") as! VC2TableViewController 
view.tableView.hidden = true
```

I also try to call method in second view controller from first view controller but this gave me only print:

Call from first view controller:

```
view.hide()
```

Method in second view controller:

```
func hide() {
  print("Work!")
  self.tableView.hidden = true
}
```

Does anybody know how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Custom delegates are much helpful.

Comment: I tried with delegates & protocols with no success. Can anyone technically explain to me why my mentioned solution does not work.

Comment: Set a flag in the second view controller in which table view exists. And in the delegate method set that flag to YES. And when loading that view controller, check this flag and hide/unhide the table. Directly calling the hide method from delegate method doesn't work. Setting a flag will work.

Comment: In my case the first view controller have a view which contains another view controller with table. So when I run an app both view controllers are already loaded. Goal is to click on the button in first view controller to hide table in second view controller. I've also tried mentioned solution but the problem is that the view controller is already loaded.